# How to run a foreground service for 10 seconds, every 5 minutes?

Tags: android, android-service, android-location, foreground-service, android-10.0

I want to run a `Foreground Service` whether the app is closed or open for, lets say, 10 seconds. After those 10 seconds have passed, the `Foreground Service` should be destroyed and be called again after 5 minutes. The `Foreground Service` I have finds the user's location and then saves it to an `SQLite` database. So basically I want to store new coordinates once, every 5 minutes, so that I can improve battery consumption.

My Service Class:

```
public class LocationService extends Service{

private final static int UPDATE_TIME = 10000;
private final static int UPDATE_DISTANCE = 0;

private LocationListener locationListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;

private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

private String latitude, longitude;

private DatabaseHelper myDb;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    createWakeLock(); //Creates a wakelock
    createNotification(); //Creates a notification if SDK version is > 26

}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mWakeLock.acquire(10*60*500L /*5 minutes*/);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.d("Location", "Updated");

            getCoordinates(location); //Gets coordinates
            insertCoordinates(latitude, longitude); //Sends coordinates to SQLite database
            sendDataToMainActivity(latitude, longitude); //Sends coordinates to MainActivity

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, UPDATE_TIME, UPDATE_DISTANCE, locationListener);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    Log.d("Service", "Destroyed");

    if(locationManager != null)
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

    mWakeLock.release();

}

private void createWakeLock() {

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    if(pm != null)
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "myApp:myWakeLock");

}

private void createNotification() {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Service")
            .setContentText("Coordinates Location Running")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);

}

private void getCoordinates(Location location) {

    this.latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    this.longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

}

private void insertCoordinates(String latitude, String longitude) {

    boolean inserted = myDb.insertData(latitude, longitude); //Insert coordinates

    //Check if insertion is completed
    if(inserted)
        Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, "Coordinates Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, "Coordinates Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void sendDataToMainActivity(String latitude, String longitude) {

    Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
    i.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
    i.putExtra("longitude",longitude);

    sendBroadcast(i);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Fused Location Api to request location updates,which will trigger a pending intent(Let's say starts an intent service) in the specified repeat interval(Give 5 minutes).So Fused Location Api reads the location every 5 minutes and send it to a intent service,from where you can do your processing.

Please refere [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alarm Manager to set an exact alarm, start service in Alarm's on receive function run the foreground service for 5 minutes than set next alarm

Answer (score 0):

"Fused Location Api" may not work in background due to power management restrictions.
You should use Alarm Manager, but there are some [limitations](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details) in latest android versions. More about DOZE [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby)

```
    AlarmManager alarm =
            (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarm == null) return;  // for instant apps

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerInMillis,
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo ac=
                new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(triggerInMillis, null);
        alarm.setAlarmClock(ac, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    } else {
        alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerInMillis,
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }
```

Comment: What is context referring to? I get an error when I type `AlarmManager alarm =
            (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);` but when I change it to `AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);` it works. I'm not sure what variable to put wherever context is. Note that I don't have a `BroadcastReceiver` class, I only have the `Service Class` I included on my question above.

Comment: context means any instance of class Context(Activity, Service, Application - they all extend Context). You have to declare your MyBroadcastReceiver as separate file public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BaseBroadcastReceiver and add to AndroidManifest <receiver android:name="<my_package_path>.MyBroadcastReceiver" /> [BroadcastReceiver example](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Comment: and your `MyBroadcastReceiver` will start your service in method `onReceive`

Comment: I created a `MyBroadcastReceiver` class and on the `onReceive` method I wrote this `Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);

        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent);`

Comment: So I got the `AlarmManager` to work. What I want though is for the `Service` to be destroyed after I insert the coordinates on my `SQLite` database. Currently the service is running indefinitely. So basically I want my `AlarmManager` to trigger my `Service` for like 10 seconds to do all the tasks, destroy it, and call it again in 5 minutes.

Comment: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26 && !InstantApps.isInstantApp(context)) {
                ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent);
            } else {
                ContextCompat.startService(context, serviceIntent);
            }`

Comment: To destroy service after insert call `stopSelf();` in your `Service`.

To repeat `AlarmManager` just restart it in `MyBroadcastReceiver`.
To get triggerInMillis
`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long triggerInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis() + delay;`

Comment: But it would be better just to start the `Service`, so that it works all the time and just use Fused Location Api there. This library is very flexible and you can setup repeat delay for update location 5mins, and insert data every update.

Comment: `LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(priority);
        locationRequest.setInterval(durationFilter / 2);
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(distanceFilter);

        try {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationUpdateCallback, looper);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        }`